# Calabash-ios. Is there any possibility to perform a scroll only for a few pixels?

Tags: ios, cucumber, calabash

[Calabash-ios] Is there any possibility to perform a scroll until a specific ui element is displayed on the center of the screen or to scroll just for some pixels?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

This is not really an answer, but you could try raising the question in the calabash-ios google group https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/calabash-ios there are some very experienced people with a lot of knowledge in that group.

Comment: Thank you so much. I have managed to find a more reliable way to get the ui element on the center of the screen:                    for index in 0..value-1
        if query("CollectionViewCell index:#{index} descendant label marked:'#{element}'").empty? == false then
          indexToFind = index
        break
        end   
      scroll_to_collection_view_item(indexToFind,0,{:scrollposition => :bottom})   
      sleep 0.5
    end

Answer (score 0):

Calabash doesn't offer this by default; it can scroll to a `UITableView` item or a `UICollectionView` item, but it can't scroll a `UIScrollView` to an arbitrary view.

So I wrote some helpers that do just that. This code is in Xamarin.iOS but I'm sure you can adapt it to whatever you like.

```
// Scrolls a given ScrollView a given amount. Doesn't check the amount.
void ScrollBy(AppResult scrollView, float amount)
{
    app.DragCoordinates(
        scrollView.Rect.CenterX, scrollView.Rect.CenterY + amount * 0.5f,
        scrollView.Rect.CenterX, scrollView.Rect.CenterY - amount * 0.5f);
}

// Scrolls a given amount down (can be negative), paging the results
void ScrollDown(AppResult scrollView, float amount)
{
    const float buffer = 50f;

    var usefulRoom = scrollView.Rect.Height - buffer * 2;
    var sign = Math.Sign(amount);
    var distance = Math.Abs(amount);
    while (distance > usefulRoom) {
        ScrollBy(scrollView, usefulRoom * sign);
        distance -= usefulRoom;
    }
    if (distance > 20f)
        ScrollBy(scrollView, distance * sign);
}

// Scrolls a given UIScrollView to center on the given element
void ScrollToElement(AppResult scrollView, AppResult element)
{
    var amount = element.Rect.CenterY - scrollView.Rect.CenterY;
    ScrollDown(scrollView, amount);
}
```

`ScrollToElement` is the main call here. Just pass it the ScrollView you want to scroll and the element it should target. You can play around with the `buffer` constant to adjust how much of the ScrollView is used for each swipe.